# Time Series Prediction: ARIMA vs. Prophet

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima, facebook-prophet

I have a working Prophet timeseries prediction model on utilization data of past two years. For the sake of science I also want to reproduce a working ARIMA Model on the data but whatever I tried, it doesn´t work.

Here is the code and plot of Prophet Model

```
m = Prophet(
    interval_width=0.95,
    growth="linear",
    seasonality_mode="multiplicative",
    yearly_seasonality=True,
    daily_seasonality=False,
    weekly_seasonality=False,
)
m.fit(train)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)
```

[image: Propeht Model Plot]

And this is the ARIMA code I have tried to run along with it´s outcome

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pmdarima as pm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Load data from a CSV file
# Replace 'your_data.csv' with the actual path to your CSV file
data = pd.read_csv('util_since_2022.csv')

# Convert the 'Date' column to datetime format
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])

# Set 'Date' as the index of the DataFrame
data.set_index('date', inplace=True)


# Split the dataset into training and testing data
train_data = data['2022-01-01':'2023-12-31']  # Data from 2022 and 2023 for training
test_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Utilization'])  # An empty DataFrame for 2024 (testing)

# Fit an ARIMA model to the training data
arima_model = pm.auto_arima(train_data, seasonal=True, m=1)  # m=1 for yearly seasonality

# Generate forecasts for 2024
forecast_periods = 365  # Number of days in 2024
forecast, conf_int = arima_model.predict(n_periods=forecast_periods, return_conf_int=True)

# Create a DataFrame to store the forecasts
forecast_dates = pd.date_range(start="2024-01-01", periods=forecast_periods, freq="D")
forecast_df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": forecast_dates, "Forecast": forecast})

# Plot the past years' data and 2024 forecast
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(train_data.index, train_data['util'], label='Past Data (2022-2023)', color='blue')
plt.plot(forecast_df['Date'], forecast_df['Forecast'], label='Forecast (2024)', color='red')

# Add labels and legend
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Utilization')
plt.title('Utilization Forecast (ARIMA)')
plt.legend()

# Plot residuals
residuals = train_data['util'] - arima_model.predict_in_sample()
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(train_data.index, residuals, label='Residuals', color='green')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Residuals')
plt.title('ARIMA Model Residuals')
plt.legend()


# Show the plot
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: ARIMA Model]
[image: ARIMA Residuals]

I wonder if someone can tell why ARIMA model won´t work. Thank you!

(Sample of data)
[image: Sample of data]

Comment: Could you post a sample of your train_data by printing train_data.head() in your code after you create it? This isn't obvious without your dataset to run through the model

Comment: Does you data have all ARIMA assumptions? Ref. https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-understanding-of-the-arima-model-d3f0751fc709

Comment: @JesseSealand I added a foto bellow

Comment: @MaheryRanaivoson well, the data is not stationary as you can see but also .diff() it to what the Residuals looks like doesn´t lead to satisfying outputs. Yet it would be interesting to understand, how to reproduce the prophet model.